# Unwanted right margin in Owl Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am trying to make full height and width slider in the header section of the page. for this i am using owl carousel and bootstrap. Everything is working fine but i am getting some right margin which i dont want. I did reset the margin and padding of the page but when i use owl carousel, i am getting this right margin. Please help me how to get rid of this margin.

Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row owl-carousel">
          <div class="item d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="left">hello</div>
            <div class="right">world</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item d-flex flex-row">
          <div class="left one">hello</div>
          <div class="right two">world</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

.left{
  height:100vh;
  width:30%;
  background-color: red;

}
 .right{
  height:100vh;
  width:70%;
  background-color: green;
}

.one{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.two{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    nav:false,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:4000,
    items:1

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add new div in div.row:

Work example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/calepsol/74dxcL91/2/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item d-flex flex-row">
              <div class="left">hello</div>
              <div class="right">world</div>
          </div>
          <div class="item d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="left one">hello</div>
            <div class="right two">world</div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the margin value in js.

```js
margin:0,
```